# Fetching Data from PostgreSQL DB and displaying in form of pie chart in Django App

Tags: django, postgresql, chart.js

I am trying to fetch the data from Progress Table(Model) that is in my PostgreSQL database.. but it shows nothing where I want to show that data in form of pie-chart. the only error it gives is something like data is being not fetched from database: [image: Error in console]

**settings.py:

```
# Django database configuration
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',   # Database engine (PostgreSQL in this case)
        'NAME': 'ProgressDB',   # Name of the database   
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',          # Leave empty to use the default PostgreSQL port (usually 5432)
    }
}
```

**MODEL.py:**

```
class Progress(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    PercentageDownload = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

**VIEW.py:**

```
# function to fetch data from progress table and use in Progress picharts on epidemiological_data page
def pie_chart(request):
    labels = []
    data = []
    print("This is executed.");
    queryset = Progress.objects.all()
    for obj in queryset:
        labels.append(obj.name)
        data.append(obj.percentagedownload)
    print("This is executed.");

    return render(request, 'django_blog/epidemiological_data.html', {
        'labels': labels,
        'data': data,
    })
```

**HTML page: **

```
<div class="progressCircles">
      <div id="container" style="width: 100%;">
          {% for label in labels %}
            <div class="chart-container">
              <canvas class="chart" id="pie-chart-{{ forloop.counter }}" style="width: 100%;"></canvas>
              <p class="chartText">{{ label }}</p> <!-- Display label below the chart -->
            </div>
          {% endfor %}
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@2.9.3/dist/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // Get the data as a JavaScript array
      var data = {{ data | safe }};
      var total = 100; // Total value (assuming the total is 100%)
      console.log("Labels:", {{ labels|safe }});
      console.log("Data:", {{ data|safe }});

      // Iterate through each data point and create a chart
      window.onload = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var chartId = 'pie-chart-' + (i + 1);
          var ctx = document.getElementById(chartId).getContext('2d');

          // Calculate the percentage for the data point
          var percentage = data[i];
          var uncompletedPercentage = total - percentage;

          // Create dynamic labels based on the data (show value only if data is provided)
          var dynamicLabels = [];
          if (percentage) {
            dynamicLabels.push(percentage + '%');
          }
          if (uncompletedPercentage) {
            dynamicLabels.push((100 - percentage) + '%');
          }

          var config = {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
              datasets: [
                {
                  data: [percentage, uncompletedPercentage],
                  backgroundColor: ['#696969', '#D3D3D3'],
                }
              ],
              labels: dynamicLabels
            },
            options: {
              responsive: true,
              legend: {
                display: false // Remove legend
              }
            }
          };
          new Chart(ctx, config);
        }
      };
    </script>
```

**Styling:**

```
<style> 
  .progressCircles {
      grid-area: progressCircles;
      margin-bottom: 30px !important;
      margin-right: 20px !important;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .chart-container{
      border-radius: 50%;
      flex: 1; /* Allow each chart to take up equal space */
      max-width: 30%; /* Adjust the width of each chart container as needed */
    }
    .chartText {
      font-size: 18px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-align: center;
      color: #006241;
  }
</style>
```

Anyone, please help.

[database Progress table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A3Gz.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8A3Gz.png)

[image: No piechart being displayed on website]

I tried printing the data in console and stuff but still it doesnt work. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You're right, it seems the data doesn't get sent to the template. You should debug that, e.g., print `data` on the python side, with the second `print("This is executed. data: ", data);`

Comment: i tried printing it on python shell, it shows data there. I wonder what could be the problem then?

Comment: I can't see any issues in your code. Maybe there's a configuration issue? I see there a `epidemiological_data.html` in the code and an `epidemiological-data` in the console, but they are probably different things.